# Menu controls do not work properly in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between these WebKit ASP:Menu fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505433/difference-between-these-webkit-aspmenu-fixes)

I am currently working on a project when I ran into a problem with my menu control.  The menu control works fine in IE and Firefox but it did not work properly in Chrome (the dropdown list wouldn’t appear).  I looked for a fix or a workaround and found the following bit of code.

```
if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0)
    {

        Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear();

    }
```

This fix I found worked fine for me, but I would like to know what is actually going on rather than just throwing it in my code and not understanding why.

Answer (score 0):

You can press F12 see how menu is rendered on client.

If you don't add Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear(); the menu is rendered using **div** which does not works.

Normally, the menu control is rendered with **table, tr, td**.